# How can I simplify my yaml by something like variable?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

my yaml file:

```yaml
env:
  major_version: 2
  minor_version: 1

name: 'build release.2.1'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release.2.1
```

I want to simplify it, only one "2", and only one "1", how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [env variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables) on each level. They are rather designed for step and runtime whereas `name` and `on` needs to be known at compile level. Thus you won't be able to replace values on `name` or `env`. And name is rather a name of the workflow and not particular run.

And for trigger you can use [patterns](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches-and-tags)

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release**
```